# PyQGIS function not working

Tags: pyqgis

I'm trying to create variable with a certain function (see code below). When I run `get_cloud()` and `print cloud` from the console, it says:

```
NameError: name 'cloud' is not defined
```

When I run the for loop outside the function, it works just fine.

```
def get_cloud():
   for layer in iface.legendInterface().layers():
        if "cloud" in layer.name():
            cloud = layer
        else:
            pass
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to `return` the layer in your function and call this when you run it:

```
def get_cloud():
    for layer in iface.legendInterface().layers():
        if "cloud" in layer.name():
            cloud = layer
    return cloud
```

Then run the following to get the layer:

```
cloud = get_cloud()
```

Now you should be able to print `cloud`.

Answer (score 1):

@Joseph

It seems working. Thanks!. I rewrote my function according to Joseph's solution below. I put `cloud = get_cloud()` inside my function because I need to connect the function with a signal in my full script. I also set the `cloud` variable to `global cloud` because my QGIS did not respond without this being set first.

```
def get_cloud():
    for layer in iface.legendInterface().layers():
            if "cloud" in layer.name():
                cloud = layer
            else:
                pass
    return cloud
    global cloud
    cloud = get_cloud()
```

Answer (score 1):

I try to understand why you make `cloud` variable global. @Joseph didn't mention that in his answer, which is correct.
I guess you can simply write, it does nothing if your layer is not named `cloud`:

```
def get_cloud():
    for layer in iface.legendInterface().layers():
        if "cloud" in layer.name():
            return layer

cloud = get_cloud()
```

Comment: I set the `cloud` variable to global because my qgis crashed/ did not respond without it being set. I think its because of recursion? I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you share your script? QGIS mustn't crash because of that.